# how to create a 3d array while using a 2d array as a parameter

Tags: c++, arrays

```
    int main()
    {
      cout << "Welcome to the Maze Game!\n";
      cout << "(press ENTER to start)";
      cin.get();
      system("cls"); 
      bool maze[ROWS][COLS];
      loadMaze(maze);

      bool map[ROWS][COLS] = {};
      int 
        x = 0, 
        y = 0;

      map[y][x] = 1;

     printMap(map, x, y);
```

FUNCTION DEFINITIONS

How can i define so that map is used as a parameter.

```
void printMap(bool array[][ROWS][COLS])
{    
        // DECIDE BETWEEN:
        // print '.' if the user has been at spot before
        // print 'x' character (NOT the value of variable x) to MARK the user's current position
        // print '#' for spots the user has NOT been yet

}
```

Comment: i want to define printMap function using map and rows and cols as parameters. Pls help me

Comment: `void printMap(bool array[ROWS][COLS])`? Now you can pass `map` to it. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: how can i pass map in the function. It is showing error

Comment: What is the error message? You're not trying to pass a 2D array to a function expecting a 3D array right?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `map` into `printMap` as:

```
void printMap(bool map [ROWS][COLS])
```

or

```
void printMap(bool map [][COLS])
```

If you want to make a 3D array from your 2D `map`, you can define a new 3D array in `printMap` and use the data from `map`. However, I highly recommend that you use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays, as they are significantly easier to use. If you are interested, [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is some documentation on `std::vector`.